# Facebook link the same as a tag?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I have shared a link in a secret facebook group. The link is a facebook page of someone. Does this person get a notification of the mention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages don't get any notification in a group even if you tag them in the secret group. I've just tagged one of my page in a secret group and I didn't receive any notification. Just to test it ;)

Same applies for a tag of a person in a secret group.

Answer (score 0):

No s/he doesn't. Unless you tag him/her, s/he won't.